# How to compare a list of tuples based in the last element with conditions

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to compare a list of tuples based in the last element of each tuple in the current list with some conditions.

So, i've this kind of list:

```
index = [
        ([('T', (0, 0)), ('T', (1, 0)), ('T', (2, 0))], (1, 0)),
        ([('T', (0, 1)), ('M', (1, 1)), ('T', (2, 1))], (1, 1)),
        ([('T', (0, 2)), ('M', (1, 2)), ('T', (2, 2))], (1, 1)),
        ([('T', (0, 3)), ('M', (1, 3)), ('T', (2, 3))], (1, 1)),
        ([('T', (0, 4)), ('T', (1, 4)), ('T', (2, 4))], (1, 0))
        ]
```

The expected output is:

```
[
    [
        [('T', (0, 0)), ('T', (1, 0)), ('T', (2, 0))],
        [('T', (0, 1)), ('M', (1, 1)), ('T', (2, 1))]
    ],
    [
        [('T', (0, 2)), ('M', (1, 2)), ('T', (2, 2))]
    ],
    [
        [('T', (0, 3)), ('M', (1, 3)), ('T', (2, 3))], 
        [('T', (0, 4)), ('T', (1, 4)), ('T', (2, 4))]
    ]
]
```

What i'm trying to do is to compare each last element of the tuples and apply some conditions.

The conditions are:

```
Compare Position k and k+1:
    1- if i found ((1,0) and (1,1)) or ((0,1) and (1,0)) 
       or ((1,1) and (1,0)) or ((1,1) and (0,1)) 
       => append to a list called `f_m` and go to `Position k+2`
    2- if i found (1,1) and (1,1) 
       => append to a list called `f_s` and go to `Position k+1`
```

and `0 <= i < len(index)`

What i've tried so far, but with a false output is:

```
def get_final(index, step = 2):
    k, i = 0, 0
    f_m, f_s = [], []
    while k < len(index):
        while i <= step:
            cond1 = (index[k+i][1][0] == 1 and index[k+i][1][1] == 0) and index[k+i+1][1][1] == 1
            cond2 = (index[k+i][1][0] == 0 and index[k+i][1][1] == 1) and index[k+i+1][1][0] == 0
            cond3 = (index[k+i][1][0] == 1 and index[k+i][1][1] == 1) and index[k+i+1][1][0] == 0

            if cond1:
                f_m += [index[k+i][0], index[k+i+1][0]]
                i += 2

            elif cond2:
                f_m += [index[k+i][0], index[k+i+1][0]]
                i += 2

            elif cond3:
                f_m += [index[k+i][0], index[k+i+1][0]]
                i += 2
            elif not cond1 and not cond2 and not cond3:
                f_s += index[k+i][0]
                i+=1

        k+=i

    print("f_m: ", f_m)
    print("f_s: ", f_s)
```

My false output is:

```
f_m:  [
        [('T', (0, 0)), ('T', (1, 0)), ('T', (2, 0))],
        [('T', (0, 1)), ('M', (1, 1)), ('T', (2, 1))]
      ]
f_s:  [('T', (0, 2)), ('M', (1, 2)), ('T', (2, 2))]
```

Comment: Downvoters can you explain what's wrong with the question ?

Comment: I think the step size doesn't makes sense here. Because if you change the step size, the condition for `i = i + step` also changes. So you need to pass that parameter also, which is not dynamic.

Comment: @MYGz Thanks for your comment. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for your answer and for the hint there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
index = [
        ([('T', (0, 0)), ('T', (1, 0)), ('T', (2, 0))], (1, 0)),
        ([('T', (0, 1)), ('M', (1, 1)), ('T', (2, 1))], (1, 1)),
        ([('T', (0, 2)), ('M', (1, 2)), ('T', (2, 2))], (1, 1)),
        ([('T', (0, 3)), ('M', (1, 3)), ('T', (2, 3))], (1, 1)),
        ([('T', (0, 4)), ('T', (1, 4)), ('T', (2, 4))], (1, 0))
        ]

newlist = []
i=0
while i<len(index):
    if index[i][1]+index[i+1][1] in [(1,0,1,1), (0,1,1,0), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,1)]:
        newlist.append([index[i][0]] + [index[i+1][0]])
        i+=2
    elif index[i][1]+index[i+1][1] == (1,1,1,1):
        newlist.append([index[i][0]])
        i+=1

print newlist
```

Output:

```
[
     [
        [('T', (0, 0)), ('T', (1, 0)), ('T', (2, 0))],
        [('T', (0, 1)), ('M', (1, 1)), ('T', (2, 1))]
     ],

     [
        [('T', (0, 2)), ('M', (1, 2)), ('T', (2, 2))]
     ],

     [
        [('T', (0, 3)), ('M', (1, 3)), ('T', (2, 3))],
        [('T', (0, 4)), ('T', (1, 4)), ('T', (2, 4))]
     ]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks. It does output what i'm expecting. But what if change the `step` ? for example with `step = 4` ?

Comment: @nexus66 Check now. Adjust the step value inside the function according to your requirement.

Comment: With `step = 4` it print an `IndexError`. The step is for comparing for example 4 tuples at once with the same logic. Maybe this is another question. Otherwise i'll accept your answer thanks.

Comment: By the way thanks for the hint of comparing tuples with this list `[(1,0,1,1), (0,1,1,0), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,1)]`. I guess i can do the rest. Thanks a lot.